# python: generate xPath selector for current node in XML tree

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I do not use XML documents often, so I know what I am looking for but cannot seem to find it and was wondering if someone who works with XML documents in python could point me in the right direction.

I am writing a python module that parses through millions of XML documents (all with different structures) that is searching for 2 nodes with characteristics relative to each other in the tree, possibly in a completely different section of the tree. Once I have identified a situation where these two nodes exist in an XML file, I would like to write the XPath selectors for the two nodes to one file and the full XML to another file so that a consumer can read these two files and navigate directly to the two nodes.

Is there a simple way to generate an XPath selector for a node that I am currently on in the tree so that a consumer can open the XML file and pass the generated XPath selector into `.findAll` or `.find` and it will return the matching node?

For example, given the following XML:

```
<hierarchy class="hierarchy" height="2560" index="0" rotation="0" width="1440">
  <android.widget.FrameLayout bounds="[0,0][1440,2560]" checkable="false" checked="false" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" clickable="false" displayed="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" index="0" long-clickable="false" package="xyz.wingman.app" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" text="">
    <android.view.ViewGroup bounds="[0,0][1440,2560]" checkable="false" checked="false" class="android.view.ViewGroup" clickable="false" displayed="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" index="0" long-clickable="false" package="xyz.wingman.app" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" text="">
      <android.view.ViewGroup bounds="[0,80][266,320]" checkable="false" checked="false" class="android.view.ViewGroup" clickable="true" displayed="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" index="0" long-clickable="false" package="xyz.wingman.app" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" text="">
        <android.widget.TextView bounds="[80,162][202,239]" checkable="false" checked="false" class="android.widget.TextView" clickable="false" displayed="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" index="0" long-clickable="false" package="xyz.wingman.app" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" text="Back" />
      </android.view.ViewGroup>
      <android.widget.TextView bounds="[598,160][843,240]" checkable="false" checked="false" class="android.widget.TextView" clickable="false" displayed="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" index="1" long-clickable="false" package="xyz.wingman.app" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" text="Support" />
      <android.widget.EditText bounds="[188,364][1404,556]" checkable="false" checked="false" class="android.widget.EditText" clickable="true" displayed="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" index="2" long-clickable="true" package="xyz.wingman.app" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" text="Search" />
      <android.widget.ScrollView bounds="[0,612][1440,2560]" checkable="false" checked="false" class="android.widget.ScrollView" clickable="false" displayed="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" index="3" long-clickable="false" package="xyz.wingman.app" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" text="">
        <android.view.ViewGroup bounds="[80,612][1360,852]" checkable="false" checked="false" class="android.view.ViewGroup" clickable="true" displayed="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" index="0" long-clickable="false" package="xyz.wingman.app" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" text="">
          <android.widget.TextView bounds="[80,692][1140,772]" checkable="false" checked="false" class="android.widget.TextView" clickable="false" displayed="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" index="0" long-clickable="false" package="xyz.wingman.app" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" text="What is premium ?" />
        </android.view.ViewGroup>
        <android.view.ViewGroup bounds="[80,856][1360,1096]" checkable="false" checked="false" class="android.view.ViewGroup" clickable="true" displayed="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" index="2" long-clickable="false" package="xyz.wingman.app" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" text="">
          <android.widget.TextView bounds="[80,936][1140,1016]" checkable="false" checked="false" class="android.widget.TextView" clickable="false" displayed="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" index="0" long-clickable="false" package="xyz.wingman.app" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" text="Why I need a premium account ?" />
        </android.view.ViewGroup>
        <android.view.ViewGroup bounds="[80,1100][1360,1340]" checkable="false" checked="false" class="android.view.ViewGroup" clickable="true" displayed="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" index="4" long-clickable="false" package="xyz.wingman.app" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" text="">
          <android.widget.TextView bounds="[80,1180][1140,1260]" checkable="false" checked="false" class="android.widget.TextView" clickable="false" displayed="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" index="0" long-clickable="false" package="xyz.wingman.app" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" text="Question" />
        </android.view.ViewGroup>
      </android.widget.ScrollView>
      <android.widget.EditText bounds="[0,612][1440,904]" checkable="false" checked="false" class="android.widget.EditText" clickable="true" displayed="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" index="4" long-clickable="true" package="xyz.wingman.app" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" text="" />
      <android.view.ViewGroup bounds="[1120,2240][1344,2464]" checkable="false" checked="false" class="android.view.ViewGroup" clickable="true" displayed="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" index="5" long-clickable="false" package="xyz.wingman.app" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" text="" />
    </android.view.ViewGroup>
  </android.widget.FrameLayout>
</hierarchy>eof
```

An element of interest in this document is this node:

```
<android.widget.EditText bounds="[188,364][1404,556]" checkable="false" checked="false" class="android.widget.EditText" clickable="true" displayed="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" index="2" long-clickable="true" package="xyz.wingman.app" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" text="Search" />
```

So, I would like the consumer to read the full XML file and the XPath selector and then return reference to this node in the tree.

Comment: Please don't delete your question and then repost it.

Comment: post the code you have tried so far

Comment: @MattDMo - It was marked in a way that was not accepting any answers. I was given two options: Edit or Delete. When I edited it, it was still marked as not accepting answers. So, I chose the delete option. I would have preferred to have the updates posted. Any guidance is welcome on how to do this correctly in the future.

Comment: @komatiraju032 - I am not sure if it is possible, "Is there a simple way to generate an XPath selector for a node...". I did not write any code because I do not know if it is possible.

Comment: Parts of my comment on your original question still stand: what specifically makes the nodes of interest, of interest? In order to search, you'll need to construct an appropriate query that allows you to find the "interesting" nodes. Once those nodes are found, getting a unique XPath is trivial. I would recommend reading through the [`lxml`](http://lxml.de) docs for explanations.

Comment: Once a closed question has been edited by the post's author, it is sent to a review queue where multiple community members vote on whether it should be reopened, just as multiple community members had voted to close it initially. It can take some time, though.

Comment: @MattDMo - I will read through `lxml`. I have been using `xml.etree.ElementTree`.